# How to use __func__ with inline assembly

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

I'm trying to add meta-data to an ELF executable by storing strings in a special section (`__dlog`). The current approach uses (abuses?) inline assembly to store the strings and nearly works as desired.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DLOG(proto...) \
        __asm__(".pushsection __dlog, \"S\", @note\n\t" \
                ".asciz \"" __FILE__ ":function_name_here:" #proto "\"\n\t" \
                ".popsection\n\t" )

int
foo(int bar)
{
    int baz = bar / 2;
    DLOG(int baz);
    return baz;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo(argc);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But ideally, the macro should automatically include the function name as a part of the string by taking advantage of the `__func__` identifier. The end result should be the string

```
file.c:foo:int baz\0
```

in a section called `__dlog`. But since `__func__` is not a string literal, gcc complains with this code

```
".asciz \"" __FILE__ ":" __func__ ":" #proto "\"\n\t"
```

Is there anyway to get the contents of `__func__` added to the string? Bonus points if the solution doesn't require custom build options or post-processing steps. Compiler is gcc 4.4 and 4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: This seems to work, it doesn't give a completely un-mangled name, but the function name is there

```
#define DLOG( proto...) \
__asm__(".pushsection __dlog, \"S\", @note\n\t" \
                ".asciz \"" __FILE__ ":%0:" #proto "\"\n\t" \
                ".popsection\n\t"  \
 : \
 :  "s" ( __func__ ) )


int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
DLOG(int argc, char*argv[]);

return 0;
}

extern "C" void test(int bar) {
DLOG(bar);
}
```

g++-4.4 test.cpp && xxd a.out | less -p test.cpp

```
0001020: 7465 7374 2e63 7070 3a24 5f5a 5a34 6d61  test.cpp:$_ZZ4ma
0001030: 696e 4538 5f5f 6675 6e63 5f5f 3a69 6e74  inE8__func__:int
0001040: 2061 7267 632c 2063 6861 722a 6172 6776   argc, char*argv
0001050: 5b5d 0074 6573 742e 6370 703a 245f 5a5a  [].test.cpp:$_ZZ
0001060: 3474 6573 7445 385f 5f66 756e 635f 5f3a  4testE8__func__:
0001070: 6261 7200 4743 433a 2028 5562 756e 7475  bar.GCC: (Ubuntu
```

Original Answer:

In gcc-3.3 using c mode, `__func__` is treated like a `const char []`. If c++ mode, and in gcc > 3.3, `__func__` is always a variable.

I guess you could use an older version of gcc, in c-mode, to accomplish this.

See the last paragraph on http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html

Comment: Well if you wanted the unmangled C++ name you'd have to use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.

Comment: @user doesn't work. Anyway `printf("%s\n",__func__)` prints an unmangled name (since my functions are `extern "C"`). It's the assembler mangling the names. Maybe if it was a dll (and thus had to preserve exported symbols)

Comment: @KitsuneYMG to view the `__dlog` section, use something like `readelf -x __dlog a.out`. On my system, this solution inserts "$__func__.2523" instead of the actual function name.

Comment: @ctuffli I used `xxd` specifically because it does nothing other than format the data. `readelf`, `dumpobj`, and `nm` could all reinterpret the data for you and miss the embedded string: `$_ZZ4mainE8__func__`

Comment: @KitsuneYMG Your solution is correct, but the analysis is a bit off. It happens that g++ includes the function name in the symbol identifier (`$_ZZ4mainE8__func__`) but gcc doesn't (`$__func__.2523`). In either case, looking up the symbol gives an offset into the `.rodata` section with the correct string value. Thanks again!

Comment: @ctuffli ok. didn't try with gcc. I figured extern "C" would give the same behavior ...